# python - how can I check if a variable has a value of -0.0?

Tags: python

I have a variable that can sometimes have a value of -0.0, and I want to change its value to 0.0 whenever this is the case.

The problem is, I can't find a nice way to check if it has a value of -0.0!

I can't use something like:

```
if a == -0.0:
  a = 0.0
```

because a can have other values like False (and False == -0.0).

I thought if I used is, then that would work, but **-0.0 is -0.0** is false!

Another idea I had was to try:

```
if str(a) == '-0.0':
  a = 0.0
```

Unfortunately, this is also problematic because a can have a value of '-0.0', which I want to keep as a string.

So, right now I can only think of doing:

```
if not isinstance(a, str) and str(a) == '-0.0':
   a = 0.0
```

which is pretty crazy considering what I want to do...

Does anyone know of any better ways to do this? Thanks so much for the help! :)

Comment: You could simply add `0.0` to your float (assuming that you have a float): this converts `-0.0` to `0.0`, and has no effect on any other value. Alternatively, look into `math.copysign`. (Obligatory disclaimer: this assumes IEEE 754 format and semantics, but that's a safe assumption in practice.)

Comment: You can check the type of your value: `if isinstance(a, float) and a==-0.0 ...` That makes much more sense than doing a string conversion

Comment: how about `np.abs`? (np.abs(-0.0)=0.0)

Comment: `math.copysign(1,a)`. returns -1 if a==-0.0 as Mark hinted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use [abs()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs) which outputs the absolute value:

```
if type(a) is float and abs(a) == 0:
    a = abs(a)
```

Therefore, a check for `a == -0.0` becomes unnecessary.

Comment: will not work in the case the op specified - when  `a = False`

Comment: how this perfect if this did not handle one of the problem you suggested - when `a = False` ???

Comment: of course it will do the trick, it is not in your answer and that is why i wrote the comment :)

Comment: I added the type check though I thought this is not rocket science.

Answer (score 1):

`if type(a) is float and a == -0.0`

Comment: I would continue on this answer. Note that `a==0.0` is okay too, then set to 0.0

Answer (score 1):

elaborating on previous answers, the simplest way would be to:

- check type
- check if equals 0.0

and in that case set to `0.0`, we don't care if a is `-0.0` or `0.0`, force `0.0` in all cases

```
if isinstance(a,float) and not a:
   a = 0.0
```